# Different forms within the same modal (log in, sign up)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been trying to understand the best way to implement multiple forms within a modal (I.e. log in, sign up, forgot password).

I'm trying to replicate functionality similar to Airbnb's; clicking "sign up" from within the log in modal doesn't render a new modal but rather swaps the contents of the current.

Is it best to build this out using conditionals within a single component? Or use a higher order modal component that takes args?

Comment: Use a single component and pass diff props for login, logout, forget passcode etc. that's how we do it.  It's always better to reuse component.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you follow [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Every function, class or in your case React component should have only one reason to change and one thing to do. That's why the best solution will be to separate components -  Login, SignUp, ForgotPassword.

Then you can create one parent component that will contain all the components I mentioned above and manage what component to show.